# Set DB path for Mongodb via terminal

Tags: mongodb, macos, mongoose, path

Trying to initialize mongod, but getting below error. I know DB path is not set correctly. How can I set DB path in Mac?

The path I'm trying to set is "/Users/kopal/Downloads/mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.2.1/bin/data"

````
2019-11-02T22:11:51.748-0400 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-11-02T22:11:51.777-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2292 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Kopals-MacBook-Air.local
2019-11-02T22:11:51.777-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.1
2019-11-02T22:11:51.777-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: edf6d45851c0b9ee15548f0f847df141764a317e
2019-11-02T22:11:51.777-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2019-11-02T22:11:51.777-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-11-02T22:11:51.777-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-11-02T22:11:51.777-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-11-02T22:11:51.777-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-11-02T22:11:51.778-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-11-02T22:11:51.786-0400 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2019-11-02T22:11:51.789-0400 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-11-02T22:11:51.789-0400 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2019-11-02T22:11:51.789-0400 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2019-11-02T22:11:51.790-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-11-02T22:11:51.790-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set mongod --dbpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448268/how-to-set-mongod-dbpath)

Comment: No, I tried a lot of stuff over Stackoverflow.

Comment: No! the error isn't the same. But I tried and it doesn't help in Mac OS

Comment: then your path would be wrong.

Comment: Yes it is! That's what I mentioned in the post as well. But I'm not able to set it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you start mongod, add the `--dbpath` option such as:

```
mongod --dbpath "/Users/kopal/Downloads/mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.2.1/bin/data"
```

or set the path in the `mongod.conf` as follows.

```
storage:
    dbPath: "/Users/kopal/Downloads/mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.2.1/bin/data"
```

Comment: Where can I find this file mongod.conf. I cannot see it. I am new to DB.

Comment: Please check the error message prints the path as you set with the option  `--dbpath`.