# How do you create a sudo mkdir for installing mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, terminal, directory, mkdir

Whenever i try to `mkdir` i get no such file or directory

[image]

Comment: MacOS protects `/`, have you tried creating the data path somewhere else?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: @joe no i haven't created any data path. how do you create one?

Comment: With [mkdir](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkdir.1.html)

Comment: @joe i have created a data folder inside the bin folder

Comment: Use the dbpath option to use that directory you created. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67546928/2282634